# How to change date datetype of df column entries

Tags: dataframe, date, datetime

Within a df, the entries of a column "Date" (n entries) are of type datetime.datetime and I want to convert every entry to type datetime.date. Can anyone help here? THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_date#pandas.to_datetime) to convert the dates to datetiem

```
df[Date] = pd.to_datetime(df[Date]).dt.date
```